# Does Passport support the new Google+ Sign-in Feature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, google-plus, passport.js

I'm preparing to build an app in which I want to enable authentication to *several* third-parties including Google. The project will be written in [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) so I've decided to use [Passport](http://passportjs.org) for my authentication module.

I know that Google [recently released](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/02/google-plus-sign-in.html) the [Google+ sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in) feature which provides additional functionality. I would like to take advantage of these features using Passport if it is provided.

**The problem is:** In reading [the Passport documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/google/) I see nothing which leads me to believe that Passport supports or does not support the new Google+ sign-in. Anyone out there with knowledge about this?

**Note:** I recognize that I could just authenticate directly, but because I'm providing authentication to several other third-parties I would like to keep everything in one place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ Sign-In is supported in 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport-google-plus

The project includes several working examples, which worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is not yet supported. I have submitted [a feature request](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/115) on GitHub. Hopefully it will be included soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just for one who is searching for this and reach this page, check here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth